# Going to a specific view controller when tapped in a notification and user is unlogged

Tags: ios, swift

I have this app in Swfit 4, and I want to go to a specific view controller. I made it work when the user is logged:

```
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Tracker", bundle: nil)

     // instantiate the view controller we want to show from storyboard
     // then we push the new view controller to it
      if  let conversationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TrackerIntroViewController") as? TrackerIntroViewController {

          conversationVC.isComingFromNotification = true

          if let mainView = self.window?.rootViewController as? MainViewController {

              let mainNavigationController = mainView.mainViewController
              let menuTableViewController = mainView.leftViewController

              if let nav2 = mainNavigationController as? UINavigationController {

                    nav2.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    nav2.pushViewController(conversationVC, animated: true)
               }

         }

}
```

But when the user is unlogged, when the user taps the notification it goes to `Tracker` but without logging in, which makes thing unusable.

I obviously need another approach for when the user is not logged, but I haven't found the solution yet.

The entry point of the app is `MainViewController: SlideMenuController`. On the mainViewController of the slide, is `MainNavigationController`, and on the leftViewController is `MenuTableViewController`

```
class MainViewController: SlideMenuController {

    var comingFromMedicationNotification: Bool = false

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        // Get the width.
        let width = self.view.bounds.width - 50.0

        if SlideMenuController.isLeft() {
            SlideMenuOptions.leftViewWidth = width
        } else {
            SlideMenuOptions.rightViewWidth = width
        }

        // Scale the content.
        SlideMenuOptions.contentViewScale = 1.0

        if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController") {

            self.mainViewController = controller

            // NEVER ENTERING HERE
            if let loginViewController = self.mainViewController?.presentedViewController as? LoginViewController {

                loginViewController.comingFromMedicationNotification = comingFromMedicationNotification
            }
        }

        if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewController") {

            // Check the side.
            if SlideMenuController.isLeft() {
                self.leftViewController = controller
            } else {
                self.rightViewController = controller
            }
        }

        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

In `MainNavigationController` is where the login is happening and if it's successful, it segue to `DashboardViewController`.

`MainNavigationController` storyboard entry point is `UINavigationController -> LoginViewController`

I have try passing a variable to the `LoginViewController` when the user tap's in the notification instead of pushing the view controller to the navigation controller, and in the `LoginViewController` if it's coming from the notification go the specific view controller.

But I can't seem to find the `LoginViewController` view controller to pass the variable.

This are things I have try in `userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive ...)` but it's not entering in any of those `ifs`

```
    conversationVC.isComingFromNotification = true


    if let mainView = self.window?.rootViewController as? MainViewController {

       let mainNavigationController = mainView.mainViewController


        if let main = mainNavigationController as? LoginViewController{
              main.comingFromMedicationNotification = true
         }

         if let main2 = mainNavigationController?.presentedViewController as? LoginViewController {
            main2.comingFromMedicationNotification = true
         }

         if let login = mainNavigationController?.presentingViewController as? LoginViewController {
              login.comingFromMedicationNotification = true
          }



 }
```

Any ideas how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really need to do is something like an AppContext. You will need a class that keeps the context of the app, and in this case the notification that came in.

Once you have received the notification, prepare an enum representing the type of notification names. Once u get a notification always check if isUserLoggedIn() and then process the request. Or else simply let the user log in.

Once log in is done, make sure you first check the Appcontext.hasNotificationToProcess() and then act on that inside ur landing view controller.

This always forces the application to to first check authentication and then process the notification.